# Create a wordpress page with archives of a category

Tags: wordpress, categories, archive

I'm a bit stumped on this one. I'd like to create a page that is an archive of all posts of a certain category - and show excerpts.  However, Reading through the Wordpress docs, they say a page cannot be a post or associated with categories.

So, I'm now wondering if this is possible or if there is a work around. I'd really like to put this on a page as I'd like to have a custom sidebar as well.  Is this possible with a custom page template?  Any other ways this can be done that I am not thinking of?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this function to functions.php and then you can call it from any page template.

If you need to create a new page template for the sidebar.

FTP, download page.php
rename page.php to page-custom.php  (custom can be anything, just make sure its page-whatever.php
In the page-custom.php
Replace the comments section with (Custom Template Name can be anything you want)

```
/**
 * Template Name: Custom Template Name
 *
*/
```

replace the loop in your new template with a call to `get_posts_custom('catSlug');`

then add this to your functions.php

```
if(!function_exists('get_posts_custom')){
function get_posts_custom($catSlug){

    $args=array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'category_name' => $catSlug,
      'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1
      );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <article class="post">
    <time class="date"><?php the_time('m.d.y') ?></time>
    <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </p>
    </article>
       <?php
      endwhile;
    }
wp_reset_query();
}
}
```

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

I didn't fully test the function, but I am using a modified version of the same code. Mine doesn't filter on the category slug, so that may need tweaking, but I did test to make sure it didnt break functions.php

Comment: This worked like a charm and is exactly what I was looking for - seems to be bug free.

Answer (score 1):

Create a page, lipsum for example.
Create a PHP file with the page-[the title].php, page-lipsum.php for this example.
Write [your loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) in that file.
FTP that file to the directory of your theme.
When you go to the URL for that page, the results should be what you're looking for.